# Salesforce Enhanced domains vs Trusted Domains

Tags: enhanced-domains

I have followed the [help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_enhanced.htm&type=5) documentation and enabled "Enhanced domains" in my org. When I block "Third Party cookies" from my Browser setting (Microsoft Edge), I see that the lightning pages are working fine. When I switch to classic mode and access a visualforce page (custom page), it is failing. I understand this is expected.

However, what roles do "Trusted Domains" entries in Setup > Session Settings > Trusted domains section play? Are they supposed to allow access to classic vf pages even when third party cookies are blocked?

Additional details below: (for whatever reasons, I cannot upload an image here)

| My Domain URL | mocksalescorp.my.salesforce.com with enhanced domains |
| --- | --- |
| **My Domain Name** | **mocksalescorp** |
| **Domain Suffix** | **Standard (*.my.salesforce.com)** |
| **Use enhanced domains** | **ON** |

**Trusted Domain entries**

| Domain | IFrame Type |
| --- | --- |
| *.mocksalescorp--c.visual.force.com | VisualforcePages |
| *.mocksalescorp--c.visualforce.com | VisualforcePages |
| *.mocksalescorp.my.salesforce.com | VisualforcePages |

Comment: Trusted Domains are for hosting SFDC pages on third party domains; I believe to solve your issue, you need to whitelist the salesforce domains in the browser settings

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_external_iframe.htm